# Canvas transform not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, transform

Suppose I have a `400x200` canvas.
I want to work in a coordinate system where `(0, 0)` is in the exact middle of the canvas and positive `y` means up and positive `x` means right.

So, I set the transform as follows:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 200, 100);
ctx.fillRect(-20, -20, 40, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></canvas>
```

So when I fill the rectangle as in the snippet above, I would expect to see a square centered in the middle of the canvas element. However, when running the above snippet (in latest Chrome) the square is demonstrably not centered. Why is this? Am I misunderstanding something about the transform matrix? If so, how *can* I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size for the canvas element isn't set properly which means the canvas defaults to 150 pixels in height, which is then stretched out using CSS. This gives the illusion of the object being offset.

To properly set canvas size use its attributes instead of CSS:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=200></canvas>
```

Also be aware of that the Y-axis is now flipped upside-down so any text and images are drawn upside-down as well. These will need local transformation to be drawn correctly.

Comment: Ah, I understand completely. I didn't realize there was a distinction between the CSS attributes and the "native" canvas attributes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the dimensions in `style` are ignored and default to the standard dimensions `300×150`. So set them properly with

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Independent of that, it can be a good idea to not rely on hard-coded dimensions, especially if you are going to use a local coordinate system anyway.

My snippet modifications:

- Use the actual canvas dimensions and scale so that the local coordinates still at least contain the square `(-100,100)×(-100,100)`.
- Add a coordinate cross before setting the transformation, that shows that even when the canvas is "wrong", the square is at the coordinate origin.
- After the transformation, add a circle at positive `y` position to show that "up" is really up.

```js
var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
var w = cnv.width, h = cnv.height;
var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,h/2); ctx.lineTo(w,h/2); 
ctx.moveTo(w/2,0); ctx.lineTo(w/2,h);
ctx.closePath(); ctx.stroke();

var scale = Math.min(w,h)/200.0;

ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, -scale, w/2, h/2);

ctx.moveTo(0,50); ctx.arc(0,50,10,0,2*Math.PI); ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillRect(-20, -20, 40, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="250"></canvas>
```